# "IONIC 3" page adding html content variable

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework

I am trying to add a variable containing html to my ionic 3 page

Ionic Page:

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>{{offeritem.data.nameprovider}}</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>
  <div>
    {{offeritem.data.detailsoffer}}
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

---

However I am getting the following

Result:

```
<p>The table contains 30 pieces:</p><ul><li>5 Philadelphia Roll</li>
<li>5 Fantasia Roll</li>
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong in this case.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is expected output?

Comment: if you use {{}}, it will consider that as string only

Comment: If I use the variable without {{}} I just get the offeritem.data.detailsoffer as a string. The expected result is a formatted html content based on the variable value. Currently I only get the html string value.

Comment: ng-bind-html use this attribute...https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-bind-html.asp..if incase of ionic2+ use [innerhtml] or other alternative

Comment: Thanks for your comments however after trying both options none of them worked. Maybe I am doing something wrong. Do you believe there is any Ionic framework or Ionic way dependency on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<span [innerHTML]="offeritem.data.detailsoffer"></span>
```

[REF](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html)

Note the section on *"Property binding or interpolation?"*

Comment: Thanks for your last answer, this allowed to me to address my search and found this <p [innerHTML]="offeritem.data.detailsoffer"></p> it works perfect now

Comment: @JADSAM can you change the correct answer then? This one is not correct.

Answer (score 14):

You should use `[innerHTML]` for ionic 3 like this:

```
<p [innerHTML]="yourVarHere"></p>
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
import {DomSanitizationService} from '@angular/platform-browser';

class....{
  public getSafehtml(html:string){
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
  }
}
```

```html
<ion-content padding>
  <div [innerHTML]="getSafehtml(offeritem.data.detailsoffer)"></div>
</ion-content>
```

If you not bypassSecurityTrustHtml then your style will not work.

Comment: I'm used DomSanitizer.